# Positioning text near arrows using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikzmark

I am struggling to get some text to appear in the right place at the end of an arrow, drawn with tikzmark.  The code is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta,patterns,calc}

%\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[4][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
        \coordinate (TopLeft)     at ($(pic cs:#2)+(-0.2em,0.9em)$);
        \coordinate (BottomRight) at ($(pic cs:#3)+(0.2em,-0.3em)$);
        %
        \path (TopLeft); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\IgnoreCoord};
        \path (BottomRight); \pgfgetlastxy{\IgnoreCoord}{\YCoord};
        \coordinate (LabelPoint) at ($(\XCoord,\YCoord)!0.5!(BottomRight)$);
        %
        \draw [red,#1] (TopLeft) rectangle (BottomRight);
        \node [below, #1, fill=none, fill opacity=1] at (LabelPoint) {#4};
    }
}


\newcommand\DrawArrow[4][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
remember picture,
overlay,
arr/.style={draw=gray,line width=2pt, {-latex}, #1},
xshift=1em,
yshift=-3ex,
]
\draw[arr]
([xshift=1ex]pic cs:#2)
 to[out=-50,in=-150,looseness=1.0] node[below=0pt] {#4}
([xshift=-1ex]pic cs:#3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\DrawArrowB[4][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
remember picture,
overlay,
arr/.style={draw=gray,line width=2pt, {-latex}, #1},
xshift=-1ex,
yshift=1ex,
]
\draw[arr]
([xshift=-1ex]pic cs:#2)
 to[out=-50,in=-150,looseness=1.0] node[below=0pt] {#4}
([xshift=-2ex]pic cs:#3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\DrawArrowC[4][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
remember picture,
overlay,
arr/.style={draw=black,line width=0.5pt, {-latex}, #1},
xshift=1.5ex,
yshift=-0.8ex,
]
\draw[arr]
([xshift=-1ex]pic cs:#2)
 to[out=100,in=10,looseness=0] node[below=10pt] {#4}
([xshift=-2ex]pic cs:#3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\DrawArrowD[4][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
remember picture,
overlay,
arr/.style={draw=black,line width=0.5pt, {-latex}, #1},
xshift=1.5ex,
yshift=-0.8ex,
]
\draw[arr]
([xshift=-1ex]pic cs:#2)
 to[out=100,in=10,looseness=0] node[below=10pt] {#4}
([xshift=8ex]pic cs:#3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
 \centering
 \caption{Issue 2}
 \begin{tabular}{@{}rrrrrrr@{}}
 \toprule
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Development year} \\
 \cmidrule(l){2-7}
 {Year} & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} \\
 \midrule
 2009  & \tikzmark{lefta}443  &        \tikzmark{leftb}1,136  &        2,128  &        2,898  &        3,403  &        3,873  \\
 2009  & 443  &        1,136  &        2,128  &        2,898  &        3,403  &        3,873  \\
 2010  &            396  &        1,333  &        2,181  &        2,986  &        3,692  &  \\
 2011  &            441  &        1,288  &        2,420  &        3,483  &       &  \\
 2012  &            359  &        1,421  &        2,864  &       &       &  \\
 2013  &            377\tikzmark{righta} &        1,363\tikzmark{rightb}  &       &       &       &  \\
 2014  &  344& - &    -  &     -  &    -  &  - \\
&\phantom{377}\tikzmark{line1end}&\phantom{1,363}\tikzmark{line2end}&&&&\\

 \end{tabular}%
 \DrawBox[thick, black]{lefta}{righta}{}
 \DrawBox[thick, black]{leftb}{rightb}{}
 \DrawArrowC{righta}{line1end}{Sum=2,016}
 \DrawArrowD{rightb}{line2end}{Sum=6,542}
 \label{tab:first two col sums}
 \end{table}%   
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]
I want the words "Sum=6,542" to appear centred under its arrow, but can't seem to be able to move the text to the right. Can anyone help please?  Also, if anyone has any more elegant ways of achieving this type of labelling on the table, then I would be pleased to see any suggestions.  For example, I wondered if it would look better if the "Sum=..." content was itself in boxes perhaps?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `node` (inside the `\DrawArrowC` and `D` command) is in the wrong position. If you say:

```
\draw (0,0) -- node{A} (2,0);
```

By default, the text `A` will be placed `midway` path (in this case, at `(1,0)`) if you put the node *after* the last coordinate, it will be placed, by default, at the very end of the path, namely at the last input coordinate:

```
\draw (0,0) -- (2,0) node{A};
```

In this case `A` will be placed at `(2,0)`. Another option is to explicitly give the node position through the `pos` key, saying

```
\draw node[pos=1]{A} (0,0) -- (2,0);
```

Where `1` is the end of the path and `0` the start. That will place the node at the path's very end coordinate (an alias for that is the key `at end`). So, if you explicitly give the `pos` (or one of its aliases `midway`, `at start` and `at end`) key to the node it will be placed wherever that `pos` key leads to.

As in regard to you question of how it looks, is certainly a question of opinion. In my own opition, doing this with Ti*k*Z is ruining the table, make a row and put the sums in it, that'd look much better.

In regard to the presented code, I do not understand why you make so much `\DrawArrowX` commands, they are the same commands with some little things changed. You can achieve the same result with only one `\DrawArrow` and extense use of Ti*k*Z styles, then you needn't remember which `\DrawArrowX` is which and you have even more flexibility, since you can change the styles mid document. Darn, you can even make styles called `A`, `B` and whatever that modify the `arr` style so you don't have several `\DrawArrowX` commands. Here is an example of how it can be done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta,patterns,calc}

%\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[4][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
        \coordinate (TopLeft)     at ($(pic cs:#2)+(-0.2em,0.9em)$);
        \coordinate (BottomRight) at ($(pic cs:#3)+(0.2em,-0.3em)$);
        %
        \path (TopLeft); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\IgnoreCoord};
        \path (BottomRight); \pgfgetlastxy{\IgnoreCoord}{\YCoord};
        \coordinate (LabelPoint) at ($(\XCoord,\YCoord)!0.5!(BottomRight)$);
        %
        \draw [red,#1] (TopLeft) rectangle (BottomRight);
        \node [below, #1, fill=none, fill opacity=1] at (LabelPoint) {#4};
    }
}

\tikzset{arr draw/.style={draw=gray,line width=2pt,-latex},
         arr to/.style={out=-50,in=-150},
         arr node/.style={below=1mm, inner sep=1pt}}

\newcommand\DrawArrow[4][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, #1]
\draw[arr draw] (pic cs:#2) to[arr to] (pic cs:#3) node[arr node] {#4};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
 \centering
 \caption{Issue 2}
 \begin{tabular}{@{}rrrrrrr@{}}
 \toprule
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Development year} \\
 \cmidrule(l){2-7}
 {Year} & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} \\
 \midrule
 2009  & \tikzmark{lefta}443  &        \tikzmark{leftb}1,136  &        2,128  &        2,898  &        3,403  &        3,873  \\
 2009  & 443  &        1,136  &        2,128  &        2,898  &        3,403  &        3,873  \\
 2010  &            396  &        1,333  &        2,181  &        2,986  &        3,692  &  \\
 2011  &            441  &        1,288  &        2,420  &        3,483  &       &  \\
 2012  &            359  &        1,421  &        2,864  &       &       &  \\
 2013  &            377\tikzmark{righta} &        1,363\tikzmark{rightb}  &       &       &       &  \\
 2014  &  344& - &    -  &     -  &    -  &  - \\
&\phantom{377}\tikzmark{line1end}&\phantom{1,363}\tikzmark{line2end}&&&&\\

 \end{tabular}%
 \DrawBox[thick, black]{lefta}{righta}{}
 \DrawBox[thick, black]{leftb}{rightb}{}
 % You can change the all the "arr's" styles globally by using \tikzset
 % in the middle of the document, then all \DrawArrow commands will follow such style
 % or locally through the optional argument of \DrawArrow, then just that command will follow that sytle.
 \DrawArrow[arr to/.style={bend left}, arr draw/.style={->}, arr node/.style={left, font=\tiny}]{righta}{line1end}{Sum=2,016}
 \DrawArrow{rightb}{line2end}{Sum=6,542}
 \label{tab:first two col sums}
 \end{table}%   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your solution is much more elegant than my clumsy attempt!

Comment: Your welcome! I've been learning Ti*k*Z for the past two months only, the manual is very long but it's quite fun (seriously, there are some funny stuff there) and instructive, I truly recomend it! `=D`