# Align TikZ arrows with qtree trees

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-arrows, linguistics

I have been encountering some problems with figuring out how to put the arrows where I want them.

Essentially, I would like to put my arrows at center of each of the following trees, but they keep scrambling over, possibly due to the page margins.

Is there anyone that could think of a solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{qtree} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\ex. \small
\a. \Tree [.DP [.NP ]. NP ].DP
\b. \Tree [.DP [.NP ]. NP ].DP
\c. \Tree [.DP [.NP ]. NP ].DP

\end{multicols}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-2, 0) -- (-2, -0.5) node[anchor=north] {[bla]};
\draw[->] (3, 0) -- (3, -0.5) node[anchor=north] {[blu]};
\draw[->] (5, 0) -- (5, -0.5) node[anchor=north] {[bli]};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Genaraly one uses \tikzmark (tikzlibrary tikzmark) to locate the end points in the text, then the  [remember picture,overlay] options to draw the arrows.  It takes two runs to locate relative origins, but alignment is generally easy and perfect.  OTOH, I have no idea what \Tree does.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but can you be more specific? I'm a newbie with `tikz`. :)

Comment: There are several examples on this site using tikzmark to locate arrows (mostly involving tabulars).  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339719/positioning-text-near-arrows-using-tikz for example.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It uses `picture`, I think. At least, my hack uses `picture` and I started from `qtree`'s code, so it certainly used `picture` 4 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Just realized, you can actually put a tree in a `\node`. One important thing to note is that you must have a space between the last part of the tree and the closing `};` of the node (perhaps obvious to you, but it caught me at first).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{qtree} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\ex. \small
\a. \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node (a) {\Tree [.DP [.NP ]. NP ].DP }; % space before }; is necessary
     \draw (a.south) -- +(0,-0.5) node[below] {[bla]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\b. \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node (a) {\Tree [.DP [.NP ]. NP ].DP };
     \draw (a.south) -- +(0,-0.5) node[below] {[blu]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\c. \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node (a) {\Tree [.DP [.NP ]. NP ].DP };
     \draw (a.south) -- +(0,-0.5) node[below] {[bli]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
% an empty line before \end{multicols} is necessary

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Original answer

If switching to `tikz-qtree` is an option, you can draw the arrow in the same `tikzpicture` as the `\Tree`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\ex. \small
\a. \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
     \Tree [.DP [.NP ] [.NP ] ]
    \draw [->] (current bounding box.south) -- +(0,-0.5) node[below] {[bla]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\b. \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \Tree [.DP [.NP ] [.NP ] ]
    \draw [->] (current bounding box.south) -- +(0,-0.5) node[below] {[bla]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\c. \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \Tree [.DP [.NP ] [.NP ] ]
    \draw [->] (current bounding box.south) -- +(0,-0.5) node[below] {[bla]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: very nice. however, my actual trees are a bit more complicated than those that I presented in my MWE, and as far as I know `tikz-qtree` does not fully supports what I need. Any other option?

Comment: @RobertP. I never draw such trees, though I note from `tikz-qtree`'s manual that there's a package called `tikz-qtree-compat` that makes some more `qtree` features available in `tikz-qtree`. You could of course make the trees manually with TikZ, but that's a lot more work, so not an ideal option. Another popular tree-drawing package is `forest`, which I understand is really powerful, but I've never really used it.

Comment: @RobertP. Just thought of a workaround, see above.

Comment: that sounds interesting! didn't think of embedding a `\Tree` command inside a node. thanks!

Comment: Nice! Since `qtree` isn't Ti*k*Z-based, you aren't nesting `tikzpicture`s ;). I'd still use Forest. (I had my fill of `qtree` and it just can't do a lot of things or can't do them without your having to wade through treacle. But it was certainly useful before there were better options available.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Forest solution which defines a new style, `add arrow=<text>`. This can be used in the tree's preamble (after the start of the Forest tree and before the specification of the tree itself). It draws an arrow from the centre of the bottom of the tree's bounding box down to a node containing the `<text>` argument wrapped in square brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{%
  add arrow/.style={
    tikz+={%
      \draw [->] (current bounding box.south) -- +(0,-.5) node [anchor=north] {[#1]};
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \ex. \small
  \a. \Forest{add arrow=bla [DP[NP][NP]]}
  \b. \Forest{add arrow=blu [DP[NP][NP]]}
  \c. \Forest{add arrow=bli [DP[NP][NP]]}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: centred arrows below trees]

As a bonus, you don't have to worry about remembering spaces before closing brackets of any kind. (It won't matter if the spaces are there, as they would be in `qtree`, but it won't care if they aren't. [Forest is worth switching to, if only for this feature, in my opinion!]